# How do I save java game while the game is off? JAVA

Tags: java, save

I have a little problem about saving game data in a directory, i tried `return` and other commands, but when I turn off the game. It doesn't save.
I also tried:

```
public class FooState implements Serializable {
    Integer a, b, c; // Integer and String
    String d, e, f;  // also implement Serializable
}

class Foo {
    static FooState allMyState = new FooState();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("gameStatus.data")))) {
            // no need to specify members individually
            oos.writeObject(allMyState);
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing works, for example i have a `JFrame` and a `JButton` and `JLabel` on the `JFrame` I made a int and the function is when i click the button int will increase (++). And I try to save my play data and when I turn off the game. It will restart. How do I save it? Please answer.

One Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class save extends JFrame {

        public static int a = 0;

        private JPanel contentPane;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        save frame = new save();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public save() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 608, 402);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JLabel lblPoints = new JLabel("Points: " + a);

        JButton btnHi = new JButton("hi");
        btnHi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                a++;
                lblPoints.setText("Points: " + a);
                save();
            }

            private int save() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return a;
            }
        });
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblPoints, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(144))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(221)
                    .addComponent(btnHi, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 161, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(27)
                    .addComponent(lblPoints)
                    .addGap(230)
                    .addComponent(btnHi)
                    .addContainerGap(60, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to save this. (When i click the button, int a will increase[++]).

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. Tell us precisely what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Your question is extremely confusing as it is.

Comment: Ok, I made one example. -Salmeh

Comment: But you haven't explained what the code was supposed to do. Do you relly expect `return a;` to save the state of your game in a file? What do you want to save? In which format? What have you tried to do it? What did it do precisely?

Comment: I tried to save the game in C::// files in format: save.data

Comment: So, where is the code trying to do that. What does it do instead of doing what you want?

Comment: I want to make a new class file and putt any code in there that can save my game data

Comment: OK. Then do it, and if you have a concrete problem with that code, post a question explaining what the problem is, and containing that code. I've asked repeatedly to post the code that has a problem, and to explain what the problem is, but you won't do it. So I can't explain what you did wrong.

Comment: I didn't do anything wrong in this code, I just don't know how do I save it(Save game stats).